# Draw a line across the baseline in a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line to show the baseline in the following node

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[font={\fontsize{40}{42}\selectfont},
     above]
     at (current page.south)
     {Quaestor};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[font={\fontsize{40}{42}\selectfont},
     above]
      (a)
     at (current page.south)
     {Quaestor};
\draw[red](a.base west)--(a.base east);     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was very fast!